how to change http method of the path in stoplight
I want to change http method of the path in stoplight, by default I am getting "GET" method, I want to change to "put", "post" methods how can i do it, what are the settings I should change.

There doesn't seem to be a method of doing this through the normal UI.
You can edit the code directly in the UI instead to change the HTTP method.
At the top right there is a "</> Code" button to display the YAML.
After clicking this you can search for your endpoint URL and change the HTTP method from "get" to a "put" or "post".
